# What is the purpose of config.xml, package.json and package-lock.json files in an ionic project and source control repository?

Tags: ionic-framework, version-control, ionic3, npm-install, package.json

1. What is the purpose of config.xml, package.json and package-lock.json files in an ionic project? I understand that new plugins added to the ionic project are registered into the config.xml and package.json file.
2. Do these files get affected by the "ionic cordova build" command? Lets say we are adding a new plugin to our ionic app, and then checking in the changes into GIT. Then with respect to only these 3 files, for the project to work correctly, is it sufficient that we only checkin the config.xml file? Are the package.json and package-lock.json files optional in GIT and will they be auto produced/generated (by referring to the config.xml) when app is rebuilt?

Comment: config.xml is responsible in definitions for ionic cli when you are building. But the actual libraries are in the node modules, which are installed via the npm and their definitions are saved in the package.json. The package-lock.json is there to ensure the version consistency across developers or build instances.

Comment: Please can you clarify when you say "config.xml is responsible in definitions for ionic cli when you are building" - so does this file get generated when building a project. So is it OK to delete this file and build project we will get a fresh config.xml file?

Comment: No, it's not ok to delete and build again - in the config.xml you define what plugins you will use and other platform specific settings - which are in turned used when you build the app. You should commit the config.xml so other people in the team all have the same config when building. And when you let's say add a new plugin, it will be added there so when somebody else builds he will have the plugin added as well.

Comment: So are both config.xml and package.json important or only config.xml - when it comes to version control?